# Woocommerce Get Attribute value in cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product where it has custom attribute(delivaryDate is attribute name) but no variations are created with it.

On the product page, the attribute is selected.

On the cart page, I am able to retrieve data on all attributes where it has variations. But the attribute where variations are not created cannot be retrieved.

Code used :

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
$item_data = $cart_item['data'];
        echo $item_data;
}
```

[image]

Screenshot of dump for reference.

So is a way to retrieve all attributes values even variation not created with those attributes.

I am looking to get attributeName1_attaributeName2 as a value from each product on cart. Any help would be appericated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done using a plugin :

Extra product options For WooCommerce and use the below code

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {$wepo_options = $cart_item['thwepof_options'];foreach($wepo_options as $key => $value){if($key == 'delivery_week'){$deliveryDays[] = $value['value'];}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with WooCommerce, it is always preferred to use their methods.

For getting attributes this would be, continuing as from `$cart_item['data'];` that you already have

```
// Get the product object for the cart item
$product = $cart_item['data'];
    
// Get the product attributes
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
 
// Iterate through each attribute
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
  // Get the attribute name only
   $attribute_name = $attribute->get_name();
  // If you want to print the attribute name too
  echo $attribute_name;
}
```

Comment: I tried it too, but the value of this attribute comes as blank.